# What can we know about the dot product of two vectors $a$ and $b$ if both $a$ and $b$ are the result of element wise multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vector-analysis, inner-products

Sorry for the wordy and confusing question title, but I couldn't come up with another way to phrase it. Here is what I am talking about. With $\odot$ signifying elementwise multiplication,

$$
z = (a \odot x)^\top (y \odot b)
$$

Now say that I know something about the dot product of $x^\top y$ where $x$ and $y$ are totally independent of $a$ and $b$. If I know that $x^\top y$ is going to be near zero, will that tell me anything about $z$, like perhaps $z < a^\top b$?

Comment: Is $x$ and $y$ here basis vectors? Are they orthogonal to each other?

Comment: they could be orthogonal, but they are not necessarily orthogonal. I am just curious if any relationship of $z$ can be drawn from the magnitude of the dot product $x^\top y$

Comment: Have you try numerical example? With non orthogonal $x$ and $y$

Comment: I think it might have interesting properties with the formalism of groups.

Comment: Replace now with know in "Now say that I now..." :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt we can do something with $x^Ty$, but we can do something with $x\odot y$. Note that
$$
  z = (a\odot x)^T(y\odot b) = \sum_i a_ix_iy_ib_i = (a\odot b)^T(x\odot y)
$$
and apply Cauchy-Schwarz to get
$$
  |z| \leq |a\odot b||x\odot y|.
$$

Something else to note is that $|x^Ty|$ is essentially smaller than $|x\odot y|$: if $e = (1,1,1,\dotsc)$ and $n$ is our dimension, then
$$
  x^Ty = e^T(x\odot y) \implies |x^Ty| \leq \sqrt n|x\odot y|.
$$